# Is it possible to override a type field?

Tags: scala, types

```
scala> class C
defined class C

scala> class subC extends C
defined class subC

scala> class A { type T = C}
defined class A

scala> class subA extends A { override type T = subC}
<console>:10: error: overriding type T in class A, which equals C;
 type T has incompatible type
      class subA extends A { override type T = subC}
                                           ^
```

In the example above, I get an error message, that I can not override the type field in class `A` ( even if the chosen type `subC` extends the class `C`).

Is overriding a type field possible at all ? And if yes, what is wrong with the example above ?

Answer (score 27):

You wouldn't speak of 'overriding' with respect to types, but rather *narrowing* their bounds.

1. `type T` ... no bounds
2. `type T <: C` ... `T` is `C` or a subtype of `C` (which is called *upper bound*)
3. `type T >: C` ... `T` is `C` or a supertype of `C` (which is called *lower bound*)
4. `type T = C` ... `T` is exactly `C` (type alias)

Therefore, if `T` is a type member of trait `A`, and `SubA` is a subtype of `A`, in case (2) `SubA` may narrow `T` to a more particular subtype `C`, whereas in case (3) it could narrow it to a higher supertype of `C`. Case (1) doesn't impose any restrictions for `SubA`, while case (4) means that `T` is 'final' so to speak.

---

This has consequences for the useability of `T` in `A`—whether it may appear as a method argument's type or a method's return type.

Example:

```
trait C { def foo = () }
trait SubC extends C { def bar = () }

trait MayNarrow1 {
  type T <: C  // allows contravariant positions in MayNarrow1
  def m(t: T): Unit = t.foo  // ...like this
}

object Narrowed1 extends MayNarrow1 {
   type T = SubC
}

object Narrowed2 extends MayNarrow1 {
  type T = SubC
  override def m(t: T): Unit = t.bar
}
```

It is possible to define method `m` in `MayNarrow1` because type `T` occurs in *contravariant position* (as a method argument's type), therefore it is still valid even if `T` is narrowed down in a subtype of `MayNarrow1` (the method body can treat `t` as if it were type `C`).

In contrast, `type T = C` inevitably fixes `T`, which would kind of correspond to making a method `final`. By fixing `T`, it can be used in a *covariant position* (as a method's return type):

```
trait Fixed extends MayNarrow1 {
  type T = C   // make that T <: C to see that it won't compile
  final def test: T = new C {}
}
```

You can now easily see that it must be forbidden to further 'override' `T`:

```
trait Impossible extends Fixed {
  override type T = SubC

  test.bar  // oops...
}
```

---

To be complete, here is the less common case of a lower bound:

```
trait MayNarrow2 {
  type T >: SubC  // allows covariant positions in MayNarrow2
  def test: T = new SubC {}
}

object Narrowed3 extends MayNarrow2 {
  type T = C
  test.foo
}

object Narrowed4 extends MayNarrow2 {
  type T = C
  override def test: T = new C {}
}
```

Comment: Note: for the subtle difference between abstract type members with bounds versus type parameters with variance annotations see Geoffrey Washburn's post in http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Scala-type-override-td1943353.html