# Why is this invalid Scala?

Tags: scala, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-type

I'm working with abstract types, and I'm wondering why this is invalid:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

class X {type T = A}
class Y extends X {override type T = B}
```

Seeing as B <: A, why can't I assign B to T?

I get this error:

```
overriding type T in class X, which equals A;
 type T has incompatible type
class Y extends X {override type T = B}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to override a type field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274729/is-it-possible-to-override-a-type-field)

Comment: I recently took a dive into type-level programming.  The blog series I wrote while doing that may be helpful to you: http://proseand.co.nz/2014/02/17/type-programming-shifting-from-values-to-types/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say this:

```
class X {type T = A}
```

you say: `T` is *exactly* `A` or `T` is an alias for `A`. It can't be anything else, including subtypes of `A`.

You probably meant this:

```
class X {type T <: A}
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind looking at my other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002651/scala-abstract-types-in-classes-within-objects

Comment: It gets to the root of my problem, which is that I can do type T <: A, but then I can't even get a sub type of T (call it B) to then satisfy B <: T in a generics bound.