# Scala: Difference between 'type A = XXX' and 'final type A = XX'?

Tags: scala, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-type

assuming I have an abstract type AA and concrete type XXX:

```
trait AA {
  type A = XXX
  final type B = XXX
}
```

In this case in any subclass of AA, both type A and B cannot be overriden, so it appears that the keyword `final` is completely redundant. Is this statement correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to prove that they're exactly identical, but I'm going to argue that they are, minus a few useless quirks.

#### Useless quirks

First and most obviously, they give different error messages. But that's not all: it's technically possible to override `A`, you just can't override it to anything other than `XXX`:

```
trait A1 extends AA {
  override type A = XXX  // Compiles, but doesn't really do anything.
}
```

On the other hand, you can't ever override `B`:

```
trait A2 extends AA {
  override type B = XXX  // Does not compile.
}
```

#### Are there any useful differences?

Again, I'm going to argue that there aren't. In a very detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11274901/2093695) to the question [Is it possible to override a type field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274729/is-it-possible-to-override-a-type-field), StackOverflow user [0__](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515054/0) notes that

> `type T = C` inevitably fixes `T`, which would kind of correspond to making a method `final`.

and

> You can now easily see that it must be forbidden to further 'override' `T`

followed by some explanation of how the type system would be inconsistent if you could override `T` to a different type. See that answer for the details.

Comment: Got ya, so I'll use final every time to fail early