# Why a concrete implementation of an abstract type cannot be used to infer ClassTag?

Tags: scala, typeclass, abstract-type

Considering the following code:

```
object DelayedClassTagInference {

  trait SS {

    type TT <: Any

    implicit val ctg: ClassTag[TT] = implicitly[ClassTag[TT]]

    val fakeCtg: ClassTag[None.type] = implicitly[ClassTag[None.type]]

  }

  class Sub1 extends SS {

    override final type TT = Int
  }

  class Sub2 extends SS {

    override final type TT = Double
  }

  class Sub3 extends SS {

    override final type TT = String
  }
}

class DelayedClassTagInference extends FunSpec {

  import DelayedClassTagInference._

  it("") {

    val sub1 = new Sub1()
    println(sub1.fakeCtg)
    println(sub1.ctg)
  }
}
```

When Sub1 & Sub2 are initialised, type TT is already determined, so ClassTag[Int] and ClassTag[Double] can be easily inferred by using type class rules.

Unfortunately, when I run the above code. I got the following result:

```
scala.None$
null
```

So the value of ctg is null, besides from triggering an NullPointerException, this also doesn't make sense. Is it a scala bag that should be fixed later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove modifier `implicit` for `val ctg` and you'll see that your code doesn't compile. You shouldn't define implicit `ClassTag`/`TypeTag`/`WeakTypeTag` manually, they should be generated by compiler automatically when type is known.

Actually when you call `implicitly[ClassTag[TT]]` the implicit `val ctg: ClassTag[TT]` you're defining right now is used, that's why it's `null` at runtime.

Implicits are resolved at compile time and, when you call `sub1.ctg`, resolving which `.ctg` is called happens at runtime (that's how subtyping polymorphism works). At compile time it's not known yet that it's `Sub1#ctg`.

---

Replace

```
implicit val ctg: ClassTag[TT] = implicitly[ClassTag[TT]]
```

with

```
def ctg(implicit tag: ClassTag[TT]): ClassTag[TT] = implicitly[ClassTag[TT]]
```

and you'll have `Int` at runtime instead of `null`.

Comment: I know, but Sub1 and Sub2 are also resolved at compile time, their method signatures should adapt accordingly

Comment: At compile time only static type of `val sub1` is known, it's runtime type is unknown yet (whether it's some specific subtype of `Sub1`, `.ctg` can be overrided there). `Sub1` doesn't have subclasses now but this is irrelevant.

Comment: Not precisely, an exact abstract type (defined by =, not <: or >:) cannot be overridden, regardless of whether declared as final or not. As a result the ClassTag can already be determined at this point. see this post for evidence: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151774/scala-difference-between-type-a-xxx-and-final-type-a-xx

Comment: I'm not talking about type member, I'm talking about method member. `.ctg` is a method. It can be overriden. At compile time it's not known that `.ctg` in `sub1.ctg` is `Sub1`'s `.ctg`.

Comment: @tribbloid Replace `implicit val ctg: ClassTag[TT] = implicitly[ClassTag[TT]]` with `def ctg(implicit tag: ClassTag[TT]): ClassTag[TT] = implicitly[ClassTag[TT]]` and you'll have `Int` at runtime instead of `null`.

Comment: That will make functions that call ctg inheritively relying on tag, which is not practial

Comment: @tribbloid Practical or not, but writing `implicit val x: X = implicitly[X]` is just wrong.

Comment: yeah you are right, I'll have to resort some other features.